# AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'chats'. Парсер для телеграмма на python (Telethon)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, asyncio, telethon

Код работал пока я не начал пытаться добавить всякие фичи. В интернет-руководстве код идентичен и работает. У меня уже руки опускаются.
Проблема связанна с этим отрывком кода:

```
    chats = []
    groups = []
    last_date = None
    size_chats = 200
    
    result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
                offset_date=last_date,
                offset_id=0,
                offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
                limit=size_chats,
                hash=0
            ))
    chats.extend(result.chats)
```

Код должен делать запрос на получение из телеграмма чатов и каналов из клиента авторизованного пользователя, отсеивать их по параметрам и записывать в список chats
Фатальная ошибка:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\po\parserTg-main\parserTg-main\main.py", line 41, in <module>
        chats.extend(result.chats)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'chats'
    sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UserMethods.__call__' was never awaited
```

Раньше такой ошибки не возникало, пытался восстановить прежний код, но это не помогло. Что бы вы сделали?